# Haskell : using the `find` function on a list of tuples

Tags: list, haskell, find, tuples

I was wondering if anyone could help me. Suppose I have a tuple of type `(String,Int)`, and a list of such tuples `[("Strength",12),("Stamina",60),("Health",100)]` .

How can I use the function `find` to extract the `Int` value of the tuple `("Stamina",60)` if I don't actually know what order the tuples are inside the list but only that a certain tuple containing the string `"Stamina"` exists?

I tried

```
value =   snd ( find ("Stamina", _ ) stats )
```

where `stats` is the list of tuples and `value` is defined as

```
  value :: a -> Int
```

..but it doesn't work :/ So any ideas? I'm specifically meant to use `find`.

Comment: Look up... [lookup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:lookup).

Comment: this is for an exercise where I'm specifically meant to use find

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use a pattern as an argument to `find`. Unfortunately, that won't work. You can only do pattern matching in a few places, such as guards and `case` expressions.

As Jubobs has said in his comment, it's ideal to use `Data.List.lookup` in this case, but using `Data.List.find` is definitely possible as well.

If you take a look at the type of `Data.List.find`, you'll see that it looks like this:

```
find :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Maybe a
```

This tells you two important things:

1. The first argument has to be a predicate function, i.e. a function that returns True when it's argument is of the value you are looking for and returns False otherwise
2. The function returns a `Maybe a`, which means it may return `Nothing` and you have to deal with this.

Creating the predicate function is pretty easy. You just need something that tests the first value of the tuple using the `==` operator, perhaps a lambda function such as this:

```
\(x, _) -> x == "Stamina"
```

And now you can call `find` like this:

```
find (\(x, _) -> x == "Stamina") stats
```

Alternatively, you could create a general function for comparing the first element of a tuple to a known value, such as the following:

```
matchFirst x (y, _) = x == y
```

And later on use the `matchFirst` function as an argument to `find`:

```
find (matchFirst "Stamina") stats
```

Now let's take a look at my second point: how do you deal with `find` not finding anything?

If you are absolutely sure that it will always succeed, you can simply use `Data.Maybe.fromJust` to extract the tuple from the `Maybe` like this:

```
value = snd $ fromJust $ find (matchFirst "Stamina") stats
```

Otherwise, if the lookup can actually fail, there are many things you can do. You can, for example, use a sensible default value with `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe` or you can change your `value` to have the type `Maybe Int`.

Finally, one last thing: you've said that `value` has the type `a -> Int`, i.e. a function that takes anything and returns an `Int`. This is not actually the case. Instead, it's just a single value.

Answer (score 0):

More alternatives, which are not necessarily better than the above ones:

Using a pattern as the OP suggested

```
find (\c -> case c of ("A", _) -> True ; _ -> False) [("B",4), ("A", 5), ("C", 7)]
```

The same, exploiting an extension

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
find (\case ("A", _) -> True ; _ -> False) [("b",4), ("A", 5), ("C", 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-liner here using `fst` and an equality `==`.

You need to import `Data.List` and `Data.Maybe`.

```
> let set stats = [("Strength",12),("Stamina",60),("Health",100)]
> snd $ fromJust $ find ((=="Strength") . fst) stats
12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fn :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> b
fn x = snd . fromJust . find ((== x) . fst)
```

Then you would have

```
tuples :: [(String, Int)]
tuples = undefined  -- a list of tuples

string :: String
string = "Stamina"

value :: Int
value = fn string tuples
```